# Is there an alternate for 'palette' while plotting barplot through seaborn object Plot(); How to remove legend when plotting with so.Plot()

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, legend, seaborn-0.12.x

I am trying to learn the seaborn object `Plot()` interface. With the traditional `sns.barplot()` we could easily define color palette for the bars.

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
sns.barplot(df, x='species', y='body_mass_g', palette='YlGnBu')
```

[image]
However, When I am trying to achieve the same with the use of Plot(),

```
so.Plot(df, x='species', y='body_mass_g').add(so.Bar(palette='YlGnBu'),so.Agg())
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Bar.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'palette'
```

I could able to assign colors to the bars by declaring `color='species'` and passing the color list in `scale()`.

```
so.Plot(df, x='species', y='body_mass_g').add(so.Bar(),so.Agg(),color='species').scale(color=['Yellow','Green','Blue'])
```

[image]

However, this comes with a legend. I tried to remove the legend by `plt.legend_.remove()`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress each layer from the legend when you call `Plot.add`. As an aside, you can also set a named palette for the color scale:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
(
    so.Plot(df, x='species', y='body_mass_g')
    .add(so.Bar(),so.Agg(), color='species', legend=False)
    .scale(color="YlGnBu")
)
```

[image]